# Rails ERD: how do you add primary_keys & timestamps attributes to an app using terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, terminal, erd

self explanatory from the title. I have to generate an ERD diagram reflecting customization for primary keys and timestamps in my app, but nothing i'm typing into terminal seems to work. currently using this resource: http://voormedia.github.io/rails-erd/customise.html

i tried something along the lines of

> rails g model Comment attribute=primary_keys,timestamps

but my Comment model remains unchanged when i open the erd pdf. any ideas? any constructive input is appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to execute the following within your Rails application root directory to generate the ERD diagram for your models:

```
$ bundle exec erd --attributes=content,primary_keys,foreign_keys,timestamps
```

Then you'll find a document called erd.pdf within your Rails application root directory.

Answer (score 1):

To add columns to an existing model from the terminal; run a migration:

`rails g migration AddPrimaryKeyToModel`,

This will generate a new file in app/db/migrate that you would edit to look as follows:

`class AddPrimaryKeyToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :model, :id, :primary_key
    add_column :model, :timestamp, :datetime
  end
end`

From the terminal, then run

`rake db:migrate`

Be aware that ActiveRecord automagically includes :id of type integer and designated as the primary_key, as well as :created_at and :updated_at of type datetime. ERD does NOT show these attributes in the diagram by default and you need to set the ERD attributes to show them in your output file.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your help. I found I could add the attribute using

> rake erd attributes=primary_keys

and

> rake erd attributes=timestamps

Answer (score 1):

`content` is the other whole attributes.

to include primary_key and foreign_key plus attributes, do as follow :

```
rake erd attributes=primary_key,foreign_key,content
```

- tested working on Rails 3.2

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a config file on your project root directory like this:

**.erdconfig**

```
title: Project Model Diagram
orientation: vertical
attributes:
  - content
  - primary_keys
  - foreign_keys
  - timestamps
```